# ADB installs apk but doesn't show under packages

Tags: android, apk, adb

I am trying to uninstall an old version of my app, and reinstall the new version via ADB on a Lollipop Android device. These are my current steps:

```
adb uninstall com.company.mypackagename
adb install app-release.apk
adb shell pm list packages
```

The original uninstall of my old app was successful and the app disappeared from the Android 5.5 device.

The new attempt to install the upgraded app returns:

```
    adb install app-release.apk
    Performing Push Install
    app-release.apk: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 10.7 MB/s (822124 bytes in 0.073s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-release.apk
    Success
```

but when I run a list of the packages, my new APK package is not there.

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

When I try to run it anyway:

```
adb shell am start -n "com.company.mypackagename/com.company.mypackagename.MainActivity"
```

I get:

```
Error: Activity class {com.company.mypackagename/com.company.mypackagename.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

So obviously it is not installing correctly, as it is not showing in packages and unable to run - even though it shows Success. What is the best way to troubleshoot this? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the issue!!!
I'm posting here because I spent way too much time trying to figure this out, since it wasn't giving me any error messages.

I was able to get a copy of the original APK from the deployment team and analyze their AndroidManifest.xml, and saw that the original APK package name was all lowercase: **"com.company.mypackagename"** but the one I was building was actually using Camel-Case **"com.company.myPackageName"**. When I tried to install it, ADB should have given an error similar to: "Application ID Does not Match", but instead it just repeatedly gave me a response of: "Success".

Hopefully this saves someone else some time!